# Estimar a distribuição de Poisson - R

Tags: r

Tenho um `grafo` e calculei a distribuição dos graus e o grau como se segue:

```
dd <- degree_distribution(graph) 
 d <- degree(graph)
```

A partir disso, estimei a `Power Law`, para ver se a minha distribuição segue a "lei de Potência" :

```
    degree = 1:max(d)
    probability = dd[-1]

    # Exclui zeros, pois log de 0 é infinito!
    nonzero.position = which(probability != 0)
    probability = probability[nonzero.position]
    degree = degree[nonzero.position]

    reg = lm(log(probability) ~ log(degree))
    cozf = coef(reg)
    #Estima a power law com base nos valores 
    power.law.fit = function(x) exp(cozf[[1]] + cozf[[2]] * log(x))
```

A partir disso, plotei os pontos e a `power law` usando o `ggplot2`. 
Resultando na imagem a seguir:

```
df <- data.frame(x = degree, y = probability)
  print(
      ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour="Distribuição"))+
        geom_point(shape = 4) +
        stat_function(fun = power.law.fit, geom = "line", aes(colour="Power Law"))+

        labs(title = "Grafo", subtitle = "Distribuição dos Graus",
             x="K", y="P(k)", colour="Legenda")+
        scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é possível observar, a minha distribuição não segue a `Power Law`! Gostaria de estimar a distribuição de `Poisson` e plotar no mesmo gráfico.
 Mesmo não tendo certeza que a minha distribuição não segue (ou segue) a `Poisson`, gostaria de plotar junto com a `Power Law`. Não tenho a mínima ideia de como estimar essa distribuição (`Poisson`) a partir dos dados, e calcular o grau médio.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Grato.

- O grafo usado para calcular a distribuição e o grau é muito grande (700 mil vértices), por isso não coloquei os dados dos grafos. A explicação da resposta pode ser baseada em um grafo qualquer.

Comment: Filipe, apesar de a pergunta estar bem formulada, ela parece fugir do escopo do site infelizmente, pois trata mais de estatística do que de programação.

Comment: Não acredito que fuja do escopo, estatística faz parte da programação, e a própria tag `r` diz `R é um ambiente e linguagem de programação de código aberto para computação estatística...`

Comment: Também concordo @knautiluz. Espero que alguém me ajude kk. Agradecido.

Comment: @Knautiluz estatística não faz parte da programação. Perguntas de estatística estão fora do escopo do site. Veja mais aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4266/como-lidar-com-uma-pergunta-que-depende-de-um-conhecimento-além-da-programação/4355#4355

Comment: Ele perguntou usando linguagem `r`, que é uma linguagem de programação voltada para estatística, ainda que a pergunta seja mais voltada para estatística. Na maioria das faculdades de programação nós temos que aprender `estatística` para poder lidar com certos casos envolvendo programação. Eu entendi o que você disse, mas mesmo assim não acredito que fuja do escopo. Agora sobre o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) sim, realmente seria melhor respondida lá, acho isso poderia ter sido comentado de primeira.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem várias formas de estimar os parâmetros de uma distribuição ([máxima verossimilhança](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), [métodos de momentos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)), [Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference)). Entrar nesse âmbito fugiria ao escopo do site, pois é uma pergunta de estatística --- isso seria melhor respondido no [cross-validated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Dito isto, você pode estimar por máxima verossimilhança usando o pacote `MASS`. Suponha que os seus dados estejam na variável `x`, vou simular uns dados para o exemplo:

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(10)
x <- rpois(n = 100, lambda = 10)
```

A função `fitdistr` do pacote `MASS` faz o ajuste por máxima verossimilhança (você também pode calcular facilmente na mão, derivando a função de log-verossimilhança e otimizando a função):

```
library(MASS)
lambda <- fitdistr(x, "poisson")
lambda
  10.2700000 
 ( 0.3204684)
```

Veja que o valor estimado ficou bem próximo do valor real.

Você também poderia ter estimado com a função de [modelos lineares generalizados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) do `R`:

```
glm(x ~ 1, family = poisson(link = identity))
```

O que vai te dar o mesmo resultado.

Entretanto, para o caso da distribuição de Poisson você nem precisa se dar ao trabalho de fazer isso. A estimativa de máxima verossimilhança do parâmetro `lambda` da distribuição de poisson é simplesmente a média:

```
mean(x)
[1] 10.27
```

Uma vez que você tem o valor de lambda, você pode calcular a densidade da distribuição de poisson usando a função `dpois()` e colocar esses valores no seu gráfico. Um exemplo abaixo:

```
hist(x, freq = FALSE, col = "lightblue")
seq <- seq.int(0, max(x))
lines(seq, dpois(seq, lambda = lambda$estimate), col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer o gráfico com ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
df  <- data.frame(x = x)
df2 <- data.frame(seq, dens = dpois(seq, lambda = mean(x)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 1, col = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_bar(aes(x = seq, y = dens), data = df2, col = "red", lwd = 1.2, width = 0.0001,  stat = "identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que eu mudei para barras ao invés de linha, pois a distribuição de poisson é discreta. Mas se você quiser colocar linhas basta mudar `geom_bar()` para `geom_line()`.  Para fazer essa alteração no gráfico base, adicione o parâmetro `type = "h"` na função `lines()`.

Comment: como eu plotaria usando o ggplot2?

Comment: @Fillipe coloquei o exemplo do ggplot2

Comment: fiz  o seguinte: 
seq <- seq.int(0, max(dgDist))
  df2 <- data.frame(seq, dens = dpois(seq, lambda = mean(dgDist)))
dgDist é a minha distribuição dos graus. Usei: geom_line(aes(x = seq, y = dens, colour="Poisson"), data = df2) mas não plota a Poisson, só plota os dados.

Comment: Percebi que ele não está criando uma sequência quando uso seq <- seq(0, max(dgDist)) (pois o maior valor é 0.75). Usei seq <- seq(0, max(dgDist),0.05) e ele plotou um gráfico assim: http://prntscr.com/ggkfvh

Comment: @Fillipe não tem como o número maximo ser 0.75, pois a variável é discreta, você está usando a variável errada.

Comment: Estranho que o resultado da poisson é esse. Usei o grau para ficar no eixo X e a distribuição do eixo Y. Troquei o seq pelo grau.

http://prntscr.com/ggli6l

Comment: @Fillipe alguma coisa no seu código  não está calculando a densidade corretamente, faz o seguinte, limpa a área de trabalho, copia o código acima e somente troque o x pelo grau, `x <- grau` ao invés do rpois no começo do código.